# How to fix when faces points on a disc are out of sync?

Tags: modeling, faces

[image: The moving point is out of sync with other slices]

I have a disc where all the black dot points for every slice are in sync, except the one circled in red in the picture above. How can I get that one back into sync where it should be on the face of that slice?

Comment: Please attach your .blend

Comment: I will give the .blend file if I have to, however, I would rather be told what I did to push it out of sync in order to know how to put it back myself since I am new to blender and need to learn it more anyways....

Comment: The other thing to bare in mind is that I wouldn't of thought it was possible to screw up the symmetry of the face points without moving the slices of the disc! :s

Comment: There are too many ways to screw up, it is much easier to do it right in the first place or let others have the blend so they might figure out what you might have done wrong and help you fix it. You don't have to do anything, if you want help, it will help to make it easier

Comment: Hey WhatAMesh. I forgot where to upload the file...

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 4):

It usually means that it’s number of vertices is different compared to the other faces.
If you add a vertex to one edge (i.e by subdividing the edge), the dot in the centre of the face moves towards the extra vertex.[image]

I don’t know what you did because I can’t look at your file, but you should know that in no way does this affect your final render… these dots only show in Edit Mode.[image]

First you need to have a look at it in ‘Vertex select’ mode by selecting the first (left) of the three buttons on the header, directly below the 3D Viewport. [image]

If you see an extra vertex (like the one highlighted on the right of my original screen shot), then select it and delete (press X, and choose ‘Dissolve Vertices’).[image]

Another way to check is to select the face while in ‘Face select’ mode…[image]

and check the number of Verts indicated in the top header, above the 3D Viewport.[image]

The one I made has one extra vertex so it tells me: Verts:4/24 (4 Verts selected out of a total of 24 on the object. It should, of course, have only 3, being a triangle.

Comment: I think I follow what you are saying SteveW. What did I actually do then to end up with this then? and how can I change it back?

Comment: Thank you! I understand what is wrong now. I found it. The outer vertice has somehow split itself in two halves and I can't consolidate them back into one. Dissolving it seems to only delete the whole slice which aint no good.I haven't completely fixed it yet but at least you have diagnosed the problemo for me. Thanks!